# Image scrollview crashes

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, image-gallery

I've implemented a scrollview with paging to scroll between some images (graphs) at full page (like the Photo app installed in the iPhone).

I found the code below that use the classical 3 pages solution (I made some small modification for my application) but, even if it "works", the scrolling seems to be slow and often after I've scrolled some images the application crashes.

I'm using Xcode 4.2 with ARC option enabled and testing both on an iPad device.
Images (10 jpg) are 2048x1539 with a mean dimension of 200/250Kb each.

Is there anyone that can help me in finding the cause of the problem ?

Thanks,
Corrado

```
const int numImages = 10;
const float kPageWidth = 1024.0f;
const float kPageHeight = 768.0f;


- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

    scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(kPageWidth * numImages, kPageHeight);
imageview1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, kPageWidth, kPageHeight)];

imageview2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(kPageWidth, 0, kPageWidth, kPageHeight)];    

imageview3 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(kPageWidth * 2, 0, kPageWidth, kPageHeight)];

scroll.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);

[imageview1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"grafico_0.jpg"]];
imageview1.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
[imageview1 setTag:1];

imageview2.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
[imageview2 setTag:2];

imageview3.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
[imageview3 setTag:3];

[scroll addSubview:imageview1];
[scroll addSubview:imageview2];
[scroll addSubview:imageview3];        
}


- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView*)scrollView {

const CGFloat currPos = scrollView.contentOffset.x;
const NSInteger selectedPage = lroundf(currPos * (1.0f / kPageWidth)); 
const NSInteger zone = 1 + (selectedPage % 3); 
const NSInteger nextPage = selectedPage + 1;
const NSInteger prevPage = selectedPage - 1;

/// Next page
if (nextPage < numImages)
{
    NSInteger nextViewTag = zone + 1;
    if (nextViewTag == 4)
        nextViewTag = 1;

    UIImageView* nextView = (UIImageView*)[scrollView viewWithTag:nextViewTag];      
    nextView.frame = (CGRect){.origin.x = nextPage * kPageHeight, .origin.y = 0.0f, kPageHeight, kPageWidth};

    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"grafico_%d.jpg", nextPage];
    UIImage* img = [UIImage imageNamed:str];
    nextView.image = img;
}


/// Prev page
if (prevPage >= 0)
{
    NSInteger prevViewTag = zone - 1;
    if (!prevViewTag)
        prevViewTag = 3;

    UIImageView* prevView = (UIImageView*)[scrollView viewWithTag:prevViewTag];      
    prevView.frame = (CGRect){.origin.x = prevPage * kPageHeight, .origin.y = 0.0f, kPageHeight, kPageWidth};

    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"grafico_%d.jpg", prevPage];
    UIImage* img = [UIImage imageNamed:str];
    prevView.image = img;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `imageNamed:` for the loading of your large images, because that method caches the images and should only be used for small images that you use multiple times in your App (like images for buttons etc.). That method is notorious for causing memory problems when used with many large images.

Switch to `imageWithContentsOfFile:` instead. Loading your images with that methods secures that the images are not cached and the memory is freed after you do not use that images any more.

If the scrolling seems to be sluggish you can move the loading of the image to a background thread using `performSelectorInBackground`:

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(retrieveImageData:) withObject:imagePath];
```

the loading of the UIImage happens in this method:

```
- (void)retrieveImageData:(NSString *)imagePath {
  NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
  UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
  [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(imageDataRetrieved:) withObject:image waitUntilDone:NO];
  [pool release];
}
```

and the attachment of the image to the UIImageView on the main thread (UI manipulations must not happen on a background Thread):

```
- (void)imageDataRetrieved:(UIImage)*image {
  yourImageView.image = image;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I replace ImageNamed with imageWithContentsOfFile and the app doesn't crash even if the scrolling is still slow.

Comment: Do you load the images as I described in my answer? What do you mean by "scrolling is slow"? That the scrolling stops for a millisecond when a new image is loading? Or that you can only scroll one image at a time?

Comment: I mean the transition between the images seems sluggish. I reduced the size of images to 1024x768 and it's a little bit better (are 2048x1539 (250Kb) images too big ?). I'm also trying to understand your second solution but it's not so clear to me (this is my first app !).

Comment: That image size should not be a problem. I am doing exactly the same in my app using the method I mentioned above. In your code you load your new image on the main thread. That means that the whole app (including the scrolling animation) is stopped until the image is fully loaded. That is the sluggishness. My method is loading the image in the background. That means that the loading does not block the whole app. It is like in real life in a factory where you call a second worker to load the image and give it back to you when it's loaded instead of you doing everything yourself.

Comment: By the way, I edited the code example in my answer. The method names did not match. Maybe that added to your confusion ;-)

Comment: I thought that the tecnique of "pre-loading" 3 images would have solved the problem. Anyway, I will try to implement your alternative solution (you're right, the method name was something that confused me). Thank you very much ! P.S. There are still a lot of secrets I need to learn ...

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Let me know when you need more assistance, it is really a wide field. Please consider accepting my answer by clicking on the white checkmark.